# ctrl + ; is globally bound after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

Recently I have manually upgraded to ubuntu `22.04` from `21.10`.

Unable to use libre office calc insert current date(`ctrl + ;`) shortcut since the shortcut is globally bound.

[image]

Comment: same problem with `ctrl+.` which does not work on visual studio code

Answer (score 13):

Seems IBUS handle `ctr+.` and `ctrl+;` to deliver awesome emoji.

In case you (as me in VS Code) prefer to use the key combo for other scopes, you can change it using the command `ibus-setup` and configure as you prefer

[image]